# Where can I ask questions about identifying non-fiction books?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I can ask about any science-fiction or fantasy book or movie (that I want to identify -- i.e. I don't know the exact title) on *SF&F*. I do the same about every movie on *Movies*. But, is there any site, where I can ask for a help in identifying non-fiction book (a biographical one, in my case)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Literature SE](http://literature.stackexchange.com).

Literature is currently in public beta - anyone can participate, and so far the site is thriving. Identification questions have been deemed on-topic, and we've had a couple of dozen of them so far. Non-fiction books are also on topic, or at least some are. Go ahead and post your question over there - let's see how it fares!

Comment: 100% right now and Beta is crafting. Thus, waiting.

Comment: @trejder Did you sign up to Literature yet? :-)

Comment: Sure thing! Ten seconds ago! :>